# Keeping 3 Floating Divs Center Stacked

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs inside of the body, and I need them to stay centered at all times, without overlapping.

I would post the link to the page but it is currently being hosted locally for testing purposes.

```css
body {
background-color: #c8dbdd;
background-image: url("http://www.splashpage.dev/wpcontent/uploads/2016/01/splashbackground.jpg");
background-position: center center; 
display:inline-block;
}

#title {
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
/* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
margin-top: 80px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
display:block;
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;
}

.carousel {
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
/* bring your own prefixes */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
height: 210px;
width: 950px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
position:fixed;
padding: 10px;
outline: #fff solid thin;
display:table;
clear:both;
display:inline-block;
}

.text {
font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 12px;
text-align:center; 
margin-bottom: 3px;
line-height: 25px;
}

.bottom {
font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
position:fixed;
bottom:20px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
color: #fff;
font-size:12px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
}

a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="title">
        <div style="text-align: center"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="carousel" id="carousel">
        <div class="text" id="text"><font size="4px"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <div class="bottom" style="text-align: center">
           <a href="http://www.splashpage.dev/">THE DESTINATIONS</a>
           <a href="http://www.splashpage.dev/mission-statement/">THE MISSION</a> 
           <a href="http://www.splashpage.dev/contact-us">CONTACT</a> 
           <a href="http://www.splashpage.dev/careers/">CAREERS</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried all kinds of position, float, clear, and margin combinations and I can get them centered but I can not keep them from overlapping.

Comment: This code is very bad formatted. I'm going to create a fiddle to help other ppl understand your question. Could you show a screenshot of what happend?

Comment: you have 2 last unclosed `<a>` tags and in `<div class="text">` no sematic tag `<font>`

Comment: Redid some of the code and ended up with this.
     ' #title {
 float: center;
 margin-top: 80px;
    }

    .carousel {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 210px;
 width: 950px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
 position:relative;
 padding: 10px;
 outline: #fff solid thin;
 display: table;
        } '


here is the screenshot:
http://i.imgur.com/jdBtmHo.jpg

those footer links are not supposed to be in that div
@StefanoSaitta

Comment: Could you try and create a JSFiddle? It's a lot easier to work with that :)

Comment: Here ya go @ChrisG 
https://jsfiddle.net/a6hqswLr/

Comment: Could you please elaborate little more your question?

Comment: @MaihanNijat I need 'title'  'carousel' and 'bottom' to stack up vertically and not overlap.

Comment: @MarioEspinoza check now: https://jsfiddle.net/a6hqswLr/2/

Comment: @MaihanNijat thank you but those bottom links are still overlapping the main text div when I resize the browser.

Comment: @MarioEspinoza I update it again. It doesn't overlap when I resize the window. Could you please provide the screenshot?

Comment: @MaihanNijat those links at the bottom are supposed to sit outside of that box, along the bottom of that screen.
http://i.imgur.com/Yc5aurn.png

Comment: @MarioEspinoza I commented the `display:table;` and increased the height of the `.bottom` class. And also changed the colour of the bottom links. I updated the fiddle. Check now. Just a quick question: Does your box ends with white border? and do you want that bottom appears under the white bordered box?

Comment: @MaihanNijat yes, the bottom div is supposed to be outside of the outline div. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS code. The `display:table;` line is commented and the height of the `.carousel` is also increased to `height:442px;` and the hyperlink text colour is changed to white as the background is black and it doesn't appear.

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700);

body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url("http://www.splashpage.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/splashbackground.jpg");
    background-position: center center; 
}

#title {
    //float: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.carousel {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 442px;
    width: 950px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
//  position:relative;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: #fff solid thin;
    //display: table;
}

.text {
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center; 
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.bottom {
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
//  position:fixed;
    bottom:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    font-size:12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```